# Matrix and eigenvalue matrix?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form, characteristic-polynomial, jordan-algebras

If we have the eigenvalues of a 6*6 matrix with values such as = [1 1 1 2 2 3], how to write different matrix based on the same eigenvalue matrix.
I really need you all to answer this question.
THANK YOU.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know what a diagonal matrix is and what the eigenvalues of a diagonal matrix are?

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. You right, I'm new to Linear Algebra, but I have used the diagonal matrix already and don't know how to write more "A" matrix based on the same eigenvalue matrix. I'll follow your description. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very easy but it may panic if you are new to linear algebra.you can write diagonal matrix. you can evaluate characteristic polynomial then you can write corresponding companion matrix. you can make different combinations of minimal polynomials from characteristic polynomial then you can write corresponding matrices with the help of jordan canonical form. you can also use the fact that similar matrices has same eigenvalues.

Comment: I'm grateful for your answer, but I'm still confused and can't calculate the different combinations of minimal polynomials. It might too much to ask, do you mind if you clarify with an example.